# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animation name: objectAnimator

Tags: android, animation, android-support-library

I am getting this error when using

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .setCustomAnimations(
                                R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out,
                                R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out)
                        .replace(R.id.content_fragment, new DaysSinceBirthSettingFragment())
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
```

But when i change it to

```
getActivity().getFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .setCustomAnimations(
                                R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out,
                                R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out)
                        .replace(R.id.content_fragment, new DaysSinceBirthSettingFragment())
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
```

It works perfect. but i need to support older version, so i have to use support-v4, which `getSupportFragmentManager()` comes from.

I read some article saying that `res/animator` is not supported by support-v4, so i also tried to move my animation XML files into `res/anim` folder and reference it by `R.anim.card_flip_right_in`

But still it didn't work, anyone can tell me what can i do?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Support fragment manager does not support animators (only animations). Exception message says that you have wrong format of animation in your xml resource, probably because you have moved animator to this xml which is wrong (because they have different notation). You need to write it in proper way: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html

Comment: i'm not using support fragments, still the exception occurs!

Answer (score 12):

if you are using support fragment add below xml files in res

Following will be the content of **anim/fragment_slide_left_enter.xml** file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
        android:toXDelta="0%p" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

following will be the content of **anim/fragment_slide_left_exit.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
        android:toXDelta="-100%p" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
        android:toAlpha="0.0" />
</set>
```

Following code will be the content of **anim/fragment_slide_right_enter.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
        android:toXDelta="0%p" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

following code will be the content of **anim/fragment_slide_right_exit.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
        android:toXDelta="100%p" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
        android:toAlpha="0.0" />
</set>
```

finally add this line in your fragment transition code

```
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_slide_left_enter,
                        R.anim.fragment_slide_left_exit,
                        R.anim.fragment_slide_right_enter,
                        R.anim.fragment_slide_right_exit)
```

Comment: It's not the answer what I was looking for, But man!! it's very useful.